# Adjust SQL query to select only one record

Tags: mysql, join, query, mysql-8.0

I have three tables:

An adjacency-list table, `territories` with fields id, alignment_id, three_left, tree_right, depth and deleted_at (omitted from table for brevity, all values null).

| id | alignent_id | tree_left | tree_right | depth | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 132 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 31 | 1 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 25 | 26 | 2 |  |

A table `profile_groups` with id and reference_name fields.

| id | reference_name |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | front.field |
| 18 | front.manager |
| 19 | front.director |

A pivot table `territory_to_profile_group` that relates `territories` with `profile_groups`

| id | territory_id | profile_group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 19 |
| 2 | 2 | 18 |
| 3 | 3 | 18 |
| 4 | 4 | 16 |

I am trying to find the deepest ancestor that matches additional criteria:

```
select  territories.id,
                territory_group_pivot.id as manager_territory_id,
                aggregated_depth
from        territories
/* there could be no matching ancestors */
left join  (
            select  territories.id,
                            min(territories.tree_left) as aggregated_tree_left,
                            min(territories.tree_right) as aggregated_tree_right,
                            min(territories.alignment_id) as aggregated_alignment_id,
                            max(territories.depth) as aggregated_depth
            from        territories 
            join (
                    select  territory_to_profile_group.territory_id
                    from        territory_to_profile_group
                    join        profile_groups on profile_groups.id = territory_to_profile_group.profile_group_id
                    where   profile_groups.reference_name in ('front.manager', 'front.director')
            ) 
            as inner_territory_group_pivot on inner_territory_group_pivot.territory_id = territories.id
            where territories.deleted_at is null
            group by territories.id
) as territory_group_pivot 
/* must match alignment */
on territory_group_pivot.aggregated_alignment_id = territories.alignment_id
/* should be properly outside the current tree */
and territory_group_pivot.aggregated_tree_left <= territories.tree_left 
and territory_group_pivot.aggregated_tree_right >= territories.tree_right

where territories.deleted_at is null
```

The desired result is this:

| id | manager_territory_id | aggregated_depth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`

Comment: If I place the order and limit into left join (select ... order by .. limit 1) i will not get any results at all, as the limit 1 will happen before the join.